# Mysql - Select a value if it exists in table1, otherwise if it doesn't, select it from table2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (table1 and table2).  I want to select the users password from table1 or table2 if their username exists in one of the tables.

Also, assume the username is unique to both tables, so there won't be any duplicates.

Sudo code

```
SELECT table1.password 
  FROM table1 
WHERE table1.username = ?

OR #(if not found)

SELECT table2.password
  FROM table2
WHERE table2.username = ?
```

Where the wild card ? = the given username.

I only want one column returned with the password value.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that the username is unique to both tables, you can use the `union` clause:

```
SELECT table1.password 
  FROM table1 
WHERE table1.username = ?

UNION

SELECT table2.password
  FROM table2
WHERE table2.username = ?
```

Comment: How to achieve this:


SELECT * FROM table1 IF table1 exists
else SELECT * FROM table2;

Answer (score 1):

something like this will give only 1 row with the üassword

```
SELECT result.password 
FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS id,table1.password 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE table1.username = ?
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,table2.password 
        FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.username = ?
) AS result 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```